# Why I can not open android manifest class in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In eclipse, if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and click the method name, you can open declaration or implementation of this method. I want to use this idea to navigate to a class in android `manifest.xml`.
All other Activity or Service work just fine, but only Receiver does not.
see code below

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.seafile.seadroid2"
      android:versionCode="20"
      android:versionName="1.0.1"
      android:installLocation="internalOnly"
      >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.SeadroidApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <receiver android:name=".OSBootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.BrowserActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.SeafileTheme"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.sync.CameraUploadService" > </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I checked if the path was right, the class exists in that path, so why can't I click to open that class?
Anyone can help?

Comment: Manifest.xml ? Class ? Do you mean you want to get to Activities, Services, and Application class from the manifest ?

Comment: Is the class name in the manifest fully qualified? Are any of the classes defined in dependent library projects?

Comment: @StephaneMathis exactly, that is what I want to do

Comment: @TedHopp yes, the class name is fully qualified, and no classes defined in dependent libs.

Comment: Dunno. Have you tried restarting Eclipse? Sometimes it just gets a little mixed up.

Comment: Manifest is not a class, it's a xml file !

Comment: @TedHopp I restarted eclipse, turned out to be the same. my eclipse edition is Luna, OS is ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: @GeorgianBenetatos but it works for Activity and Service

Comment: Try to put the receiver with the full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your receiver is not using the full path. Try changing the declaration from:

```
<receiver android:name=".OSBootReceiver" >
    ...
</receiver>
```

to:

```
<receiver android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.OSBootReceiver" >
    ...
</receiver>
```

I've found that Eclipse will only respond to a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click in a manifest file if the name is fully qualified.

Comment: I've used the fully qualified path and still linking to <receiver> doesn't work. Acitvities and services without the full path DO work. This is linking with CMD+click on Mac, maybe that's the difference?

Comment: @Rule - Weird. Perhaps it's something to do with the Mac version of Eclipse (something about which I know very little). I'm surprised that the linking is with CMD-click instead of CTRL-click.

Answer (score 0):

Controls if all the check are enabled.

see

> General > Editors > Text Editors > Hyperlinking preference page.

Comment: All checkboxes are checked